# How to generate 16 numbers randomly in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c

I need to generate 16 random numbers in a line,  in Xcode. Looking for help..

I've looked online for a solution but have not found one that matches what i'm looking to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the arc4random function

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int r = arc4random();
```

If you want to limit the range of the randomly generated numbers, for example select numbers up to 100 you need the following:

```
int r = arc4random() % 100;
```

Use it within a for loop so you can create 16 random numbers.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
        int r = arc4random() % 9;
        NSLog(@"%d", r);
    }
```

If you want to store them in an Array and print them, you have to convert them to NSNumbers first. A complete solution would be:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    int r = arc4random() % 9;
    NSLog(@"%d", r);
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:r];
    [array addObject:number];
}

NSArray * secondArray = [array valueForKey:@"stringValue"]; //Convert the firstArray to array of strings

NSString * allInALine = [secondArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", allInALine); //Prints the 16 numbers with a space between them
```

Comment: I actually want to combine 16 numbers together.. 16 different number not 16 sets of numbers.

Comment: this prints 16 numbers with a space between them: for example 1 5 20 25 56 etc. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: No i was looking for 16 digits total which are random.

Comment: Edited my answer so the code does what you want